# Telerik ASP.NET MVC's Combobox page-loading

Tags: combobox, telerik, scalability

Does Telerik has a plan to make ASP.NET MVC's combobox have a feature of only fetching the data brought into view(as scrolled by user). The current ASP.NET MVC combobox fetch all rows even though they are not brought into view by the user.  If they don't have that feature yet, I'm worried that ASP.NET MVC combobox would not scale in real-world usage.

contrast this ASP.NET MVC combobox:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/combobox

with this ASP.NET combobox:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/populatingwithdata/autocompletesql/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is not available yet in the MVC combobox. You can specify some minimum number of characters that should be entered before an ajax request is made. Then on the server side filter the data so you don't return it all to the end user.

Comment: How do you specify the number of characters before the ajax request is made?